# Problems with Unicode

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unicode

Here are the codes

```
 <textarea id="ta1" name="MyEA" runat="server" ></textarea>
    ...
```

---

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into feat_tab(feat,user_abbr,feat2,upd_date)values(@adv,@abbr,@feat2,getdate()) ", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@adv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ta1.InnerHtml;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@abbr", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_userabbr.Text.Trim();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@feat2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_feat2.Text.Trim();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

...
```

and I put this **"任何问题"** on the page but it is then saved within Sql server 2012 as
**任何?**?

why?

Comment: Did you see `SqlDbType.NVarChar` and ` cmd.Parameters.Add("@adv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ta1.InnerHtml;`  ? That is NVarchar dude

Comment: Is the value correct before going to SQL Server?

Comment: What is the encoding you're using in your app? Do you have the correct encoding on the page and in web.config?

Comment: @RacilHilan , What you mean? My text area is a third party tool (like CK Editor), That gives the encoded values

Comment: I have just tested your table structure and passing the data directly and it worked fine also made console app and that also worked.  Maybe ensure you have the latest sql native client.

Comment: Actually ignore that forget .net implements it's own and doesn't rely on the native one.  Do ensure you have all the updates for .net installed.

Comment: Okay ! I will confirm it later. But I have already checked that, everything good.  but i will check one more time for you !

Comment: Which collation would it be? Does the collation of the column match the collation of the data?

Comment: It doesn't matter where your text area coming from, unless they alter the encoding in it, which I really doubt. Your page and web.config are the ones that decide the encoding. I cannot put that in the comment, so I will post it as an answer and we can discuss it there.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the encoding to be handled correctly, you need the two sides to have the same encoding. In other words, your database and app encoding must match. For example, you can set both to UTF-16:

1) In the database: set the collation on the field to UTF-16.

2) In the web page (or the master page if you have one):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16" />
```

3) In your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization 
       fileEncoding="utf-16" 
       requestEncoding="utf-16" 
       responseEncoding="utf-16" />
</system.web>
```